# adding an "active" class to parent and child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to add an active class to both parent and child element if a user clicks on the child element in a list. My html is as follows:-

```
<ul class="tabs">
      <li class="accordion"><a href="#tab1">Bar</a>
         <ul class="sub">
           <li>lorem/li>
           <li>ipsum</li>
           <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
           <li>Dolor Sit Amet</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
```

and I'm using the jquery code below to add an active class to both the parent and child element yet I'm having errors:-

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active").find(".sub li").removeClass("active"); 
      $(this).addClass("active").find(".sub li").addClass("active"); 
});
```

Then styled my active class in CSS. say example

```
.active {background:#EFEFEF;}
```

only the clicked (this) child element should have the active class applied to it and not the whole li child elements. Now together with the child li (say lorem) the parent li (bar) should also be highlighted. Think of it like a tree accordion menu where both the selected child element and it's parent li have the active class with different css styling.

Comment: Do you realize that if a parent has the class `active`, all children will respond to the `.active` CSS styling also?  Unless your CSS rules are more detailed than your example, you don't need to add `active`to the child.

Comment: yep man. the the parent and child elements have different CSS styling hence this question

Comment: There are quite a few child elements in the list.  Which one are you referring to that the user should click on?  The css selector will be different for each. For example: `ul.tabs > li` or `ul.sub > li`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just going to make an assumption here that you only want to add the active class to the list items like so: http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/

I hope that's what you were looking for. Cheers.

Comment: yep. This I've achieved with my own jquery script. What I'm finding difficult to achieve is to make the bar(parent) also active once any of it's children is clicked. Well to make things clearer, it's an accordion menu I'm designing. so like when the child elements are clicked, both the child and parent elements should have the active class (with different css styles). Can you help me out bro?

Comment: Could you tell me the exact elements you're want the .active class on, is it the <ul> or <a>? Is this what you mean (I've also added active to the <a>): http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/2/

Comment: you sir deserve a Grammy award XD

Comment: please check this fiddle modification http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/6/. using the same code, how can I still add active (green color) to the main nav list? Please help me out bro

Comment: @Santy hi, better remain to stylize it with classes instead of identifiers. http://jsfiddle.net/gfkM4/28/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
      $("ul.tabs li, .sub li").removeClass("active"); 
      $(this).find(".sub li").andSelf().addClass("active"); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** http://jsfiddle.net/4G7TJ/3/ (per your new requirement that only one child is selected)

```
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    // remove .active from all li descendants
    $("ul.tabs li").not(this).removeClass("active");

    $(this)
        .addClass("active")
        .not('.accordion')
        .parents("li:first").addClass("active");
    return false;
});
```

The idea behind returning false is to prevent the 'click' event from being propagated to the parent `li` when a child `li` is clicked, since that would undo the styling change on the child.

---

**Update**: Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/4G7TJ/1/

```
// only trigger the click on direct descendants
// (otherwise the kids get the event first and this won't work)
$("ul.tabs > li").click(function() {

    // remove .active from all li descendants
    $("ul.tabs li").not(this).removeClass("active");

    $(this).addClass("active").find(".sub li").addClass("active");
});
```

Also - `<li>lorem/li>` isn't closed, meaning that all of your tags are likely mismatched and you can't be sure what the 'current' list-item is (and in which list) when you click.

Comment: still doesn't work. yep fixed all the typos. The parent element however get's the class "active" upon hovering on the child elements and this is the same results with all the other codes here so far! :(. The child element is however working perfectly

Comment: @santy http://jsfiddle.net/4G7TJ/ -- Does that capture the effect you are looking for?

Comment: almost that man. My only concern is, only one child li element should be highlited together with the parent. So say if Lorem is clicked, only Lorem, and it's parent (Bar) will be highlighted

Comment: @santy Updated. Note 'Bar' is only a hyperlink, the parent is the whole thing. If you only want 'Bar' highlighted, you probably will want to style the anchor link rather than the `li`. Take a look and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is demo for applying active class on accordion menu option using jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="accordion">
    <a href="#tab1">
      Bar
    </a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>
        lorem
      </li>
      <li>
        ipsum
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </li>
      <li>
        Dolor Sit Amet
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="accordion">
    <a href="#tab2">
      Foo
    </a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>
        lorem
      </li>
      <li>
        ipsum
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </li>
      <li>
        Dolor Sit Amet
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabs li{
  list-style:none;
}
.tabs li:hover{
  background:#88ccf9;
}
.tabs li a{
  color:#334499;
}
.tabs{
  border:1px solid #3344ff;
  background:#dcfcff;
  padding:10px;
}
.tabs .accordion .sub{
  padding:3px 3px 3px 18px;
  display:none;
}
.tabs .active .sub{
  display:block;
}
.tabs li.active{
  background:#77d9c9;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        // remove .active from all li descendants
        $("ul.tabs li").not(this).removeClass("active");
        //hide all sub menu except current active
        $("ul.tabs li").not(this).find(".sub").hide(400);
        //apply active class on current selected menu
        $(this).addClass("active");

        //check if sub menu exists
        if($(this).find(".sub").length>0){
              //show the selected sub menu 
              $(this).find(".sub").show(500);
               //apply active class on all sub menu options
              $(this).find(".sub li").andSelf().addClass("active");
        } 
    });
});
```

I have done complete bin on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpa5

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just played the style of the 'a' tag in the 'if' title condition. Not so beautiful code but simple and works fine.

Try this :

```
@if($title == "A" || $title == "B" || $title == "C")
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="color: white;background-color: #fe5c2d;"> File Data
   </a>
@else
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> File Data
   </a>
@endif
```